# How to spawn in item with a tile entity? 1.11.2

Tags: entity-framework, minecraft, spawn, minecraft-forge

I was wondering on how to get my tile entity to spawn an item when it has been taken out of it? for example if it was an ATM and you pressed the button to take out $20. I have the entity set up but the tutorial I'm following uses worldOBj.(stuff)

When I tried to figure it out myself it was only giving me the option to do something like World.spawnEntity() and it only accepts entities not items.

The Tile entity extends minecrafts TileEnity and imports itemStack and tileEntity.

Any help what line of code would accomplish this is appreciated! I'm new to modding

Comment: So, what you want to do is drop a specific ItemStack, yes?  Might want to look at `BlockDropper` for inspiration as to how vanilla does it.

Comment: Items are spawned in the world as `EntityItem`.